# Idealforms: preselect option with addfield

Tags: jquery, idealforms

i'm really stuck trying to figure out how to preselect an option in a dropdown thats added using addfield.
the text fields i add like this i can populate using: value: 'xyz' in the field's array. but the select box doesnt recognise that.
could anyone please help.
(also, i'm using Idealforms 2, not 3)
my code for the dropdown looks like this:

```
var newFields = [
    {
    name: 'accounttype',
    label: 'Account type',
    filters: 'exclude',
    data: { exclude: ['default'] },
    errors: { exclude: 'Please select account type' },
    type: 'select',
    list: [
        'Select account type::default',
        'Current/Cheque::1',
        'Savings::2',
        'Transmission::3'
    ],  
    value: 'Transmission::3',
    addAfter: 'pay-options'
},
```

i've tried all the possible options in the value line, also tried selecting it later using jquery below on in case its a AJAX timing issue. but still very stuck. please could someone take a look :)

```
var my_accounttype = '3';    
    $('#accounttype option').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this); 
        if ($this.val() == my_accounttype ) {
            alert ($this.val() + " == " + my_accounttype ); 
            $this.prop('selected', true);
            return false; 
        }
    });
```

anyone have any ideas?
V

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
bit of a mission but here goes...
all you have to do is find the actual element after conversion from html select input to an idealforms styled list. then simulate a click!

```
( document ).ready(function() {
        dateforuse = gup('salarydate3');
        if(dateforuse[0] == 0){ dateforuse = dateforuse[1]; } //in case date below 10 and leads with a zero
        $( ".salarydate3 li ul li" ).each(function( index ) {
            if( $( this ).text() == dateforuse){
                $( this ).click();
            }
        });
});
```